# Can't import dump database to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pybossa

I'm using pybossa and PostgreSQL. 
My list of databases are like this:

[image: db]
I have a dump collection for pybosssa database named: `pybossa-db-oct2-final.bak`

I want to import it on the pybossa db. The problem is that I'm not so familiar with PostgreSQL. I checked this page https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/backup-dump.html but there are some instructions only for compressed dumps but not for `.bak` files.

I tried like this:

```
pg_dump pybossa pybossa-db-oct2-final.bak
```

But this didn't work? I need help can someone help me, please?

Edit:

I tried this command:

```
 pg_restore -d pybossa /home/sagar/Download/sample_dbump
```

I get this:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
pg_restore: [archiver] could not open input file "/home/sagar/Download/sample_dbump
": No such file or directory
```

In this `/home/sagar/Download/sample_dbump` my file `pybossa-db-oct2-final.bak` is found, I used `pwd` command to define the path

Comment: "didn't work" is not a valid Postgres error message. `pg_dump` will **export** the data of a database to a SQL script. It will **not** import anything. To _import_ a dump it depends on what format that `.bak` file is. If that is a SQL script you need to run it through psql. If it is a custom format you need to use `pg_restore`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually I checked also the pg_restore command , I tried like this but nothing still pg_restore -d pybossa /home/sagar/Download/sample_dbump

Comment: What is the error message you get? And what format is that `.bak` file? How was that dump taken?

Comment: So that `.bak` is most probably a SQL dump. See here for many questions on how to run a SQL script with `psql`: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+%5Bpsql%5D+run+script

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name pg_dump is used to generate that bat  (backup) file

Comment: `pg_dump` can generate three different types of dumps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126604/discussion-between-egjupss-and-a-horse-with-no-name).